# Why is the Venus Climate Orbiter also called Planet-C?

Tags: venus, akatsuki

The Venus Climate Orbiter is also known as [*Akatsuki*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akatsuki_(spacecraft)) and Planet-C.  **Why is a Venus spacecraft called Planet-C?**  Venus is the *second* planet from the Sun, but C is the *third* letter of the alphabet.

Comment: "*Venus is the second planet from the Sun*" [OR IS IT?!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IfX1hJS0iGM) (it is)

Answer (score 20):

It's the third in a series.

- [Planet-A](https://space.skyrocket.de/doc_sdat/planet-a.htm), "Suiseu" studied Halley's comet.
- [Planet-B](https://space.skyrocket.de/doc_sdat/planet-b.htm), "Nozomi" visited Mars.

Looks like there's a [Planet-D](http://wtk.gfd-dennou.org/2020-04-22/yamashiro/pub/Planet-D_V2_1_open.pdf) (PDF link) planned for visiting Venus, too.

Comment: And there are also the MUSES, SOLAR, EXOS and ASTRO series counting by letters.

Answer (score 10):

An [ISAS](https://www.isas.jaxa.jp/en/) mission in development is known by a series and a letter. After successful launch, it gets a name, based on suggestions from its developers. One I worked on, ASTRO-E, unsuccessfully launched, was rebuilt as ASTRO-E2. Once successfully launched, it was named "Suzaku", after a mythical bird that is reborn in some stories.

Comment: Is ISAS the Institute of Space and Astronautical Science? https://www.isas.jaxa.jp/en/

Comment: @OrganicMarble Yes. A somewhat odd translation of 宇宙科学研究所, which is more literally "space science research institute".